# Tangent line to a parametrised (differentiable) curve.

Tags: differential-geometry

I just read that given $\alpha : I \rightarrow R^3$ a parametrised differentiable curve, for each $t \in I$ where $\alpha '(t) \neq 0$, there is a well-defined straight line that contains the point $\alpha (t)$ and the vector $\alpha ' (t)$. I understand this line is called the tangent line to $\alpha $ at $t$. Could somebody give me an example of how the equation of this tangent line is derived? For example, how could I find the tangent line of the tractrix at $t=t_0$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

$$x=t, y= t^2+1, z= 2-3t^3 $$

Find the tangent line at $t=1$

First you notice that at $t=1$, we have $$ (x,y,z) = (1,2,-1)$$

On the other hand $$ (x',y',z') = (1,2t,-9t^2)=(1,2,-9)$$

Thus the equation of tangent line is

$$ x=1+t\\ y=2+2t\\z=-1-9t $$

Answer (score 1):

Given a curve $\alpha : I \to \mathbb{R}^3$, its velocity vector at a point $t_0$ is $\alpha'(t_0)$. The line tangent to the curve that this point is then formed as follows: you start at the point $\alpha(t_0)$, and then you travel parallel to the velocity vector. So it would be the line parametrized in $s$ by 
$$
\alpha(t_0) + s\alpha'(t_0), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ s \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: I guess the curve could also be written $( x(t_0)+ \lambda (x'(t_0)-x(t_0) ), y(t_0)+\lambda (y'(t_0)-y(t_0) )$.

Comment: For the tangent line of $\alpha (t) = (x(t), y(t))$, would the slope be $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$?

Comment: Yeah it would,  but that's a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: you're right, how would you calculate the slope in $\mathbb{R}^3$?